# Elegant way to use CUBEVALUE formula

Tags: vba, excel, ssas, cube

I am working on cube that contains financial reporting data. It has fact table with monthly cost and income figures, as well as Time, Ledger, Account, BusinessUnit dimensions. My purpose is to use formula to retrieve values from Cube into Excel. I know that Cubevalue formula is very versatile and you can retrieve data in various levels of aggregation. But I would like have simple formula to get a value out of cube if I ask for specific Time, Ledger, Account and BusinessUnit. I have written following formula that does it:

=CUBEVALUE("ServerAAA";"[Dim BU].[Business Unit].&[Company1]";"[Dim Ledger].[Ledger].&[AC]";"[Measures].[Amount]";"[Dim Account].[Account Parent].&[P0168]";"[Dim Date].[CalHierarchy].[Mnd].&[2014]&[Jan]")

But this is in No way elegant...I would like to have formula similar to this:

CUBEVALUE("ServerAAA";$B$2;$A$4;$A9;B$7;B8) and then avoid entering CubeMember formulas into referred cells, just entering values like Company1 for BusinessUnit, AC for Ledger, 2014 and Jan to define Time, P0168 for account.

Was thinking of creating user defined Function via VBA, but maybe there is easier solution???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the short version of the CUBEVALUE formula if none of the dimensions overlap. So, you can use the suggested version of `CUBEVALUE("ServerAAA";$B$2;$A$4;$A9;B$7;B8)` if the underlying dimensions `Company`, `Business Unit`, `Account`, `Account Parent`, etc. are unique. By that I mean that all possible occurences of `Account` may only show up in this dimension. If any `Account` could also possibly show up in `Parent Account` then the truncated version of the CUBEVALUE formula you suggested wouldn't work because Excel wouldn't know if you are referring to the `Parent Account` or the `Account` itself.

I once had the same problem and found out that - as long as all dimensions are independent from one another - Excel can tell which dimension you are referring to and automatically filters by this dimension.

Comment: Very valuable input Ralph! Tried replacing "[Dim Ledger].[Ledger].&[AC]" with only "[AC]" and it worked! Accounts gave error message as you suggested. It makes sense what you explained... I have set up Parent Child relationship in account dimension, so I can not avoid account multi accurance in AccountParent column...

Comment: @arunas-jocius: if this is the answer you've been looking for then please close it. Otherwise, let me know...

Comment: @arunas-jocius: No problem. Just go to [this site and take the StackOverflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Shouldn't take you more than five minutes. Like this you'll also earn your next [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges): "Informed".